# How can I use a cookie to enter and download a web page in Python

Tags: python

How do I download a webpage using a cookie in Python.
I am successfully using curl to do the job, but I would like to use a Python equivalent. I think pycurl should do it but I cant find an example that allows the user to input just a cookie.
The curl bash line I am using is:-

```
curl -b "*cookie*" http://www.example.com/home.php -o home.html
```

Thank you.
Goon

Answer (score 2):

Use [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) and [Cookie](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html) modules in the standard library to create/store cookies, to actually make requests I recommend [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) over `urllib2` in the standard library.

```
import Cookie, cookielib, requests
# create cookiejar
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
# create cookie
ck = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
ck.name = 'value'
ck.expires = 0
ck.path = '/'
ck.domain = 'www.example.com'
# add cookie to cookiejar
cj.set_cookie(ck)
# use cookiejar to make request
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/home.php', cookies=cj)
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

the home page shows an example using cookies.